# How to control the Widgets in QGridLayout that should be painted in GUI?

Tags: c++, qt

In my application I have a `QGridLayout` which covers the majority of the `Window`. In it I have added a sequence of `QLineEdit` & `QLabel` objects. Currently when the no of `QLineEdit` objects > 500 && `QLabel` objects > 500 the `GUI` is significantly slow & for greater values does not operate properly. Also most of these widgets are not visible in the window, they need to be scrolled to be viewd.
Since I am adding so many `widgets` in the `grid layout` (by looping & calling `repaint` after the loop) the painting takes lots of time.
So I have an idea for the solution that even though my `widgets` are added in the `Grid Layout` not everybody are painted. I want to have a `rectangle` within which all `widgets` are painted & the **co-ordinates of the rectangle will be updated whenever the the window is scrolled**. But I dont know how to do this. So I wanted to know is it possible to do that?
And if possible please add a small sample code so that I can understand how to implement that.
Thank You.

**UPDATE** : Adding an image to depict the sitatuion.

```
Black Rectangle = QGridLayout say myGid.

Red Rectangle = Bounding Rectangle which is approximately same size as Main Window of my Application.

Green Rectangle = Widgets in myGrid.
```

`Green Rectangle filled with yellow = Widgets shown in Main Window` *(only these widgets should be considered for call to `repaint`)*, rest of the unfilled rectangles are widgets present in `myGrid` but not be considered for call to `repaint`.
Thus when I scroll in my main application, the co-ordinates of `red rectangle` are updated & all the `widgets bounded by it are considered for repaint.`
I hope I made the problem simple to understand.
[image]

Comment: I understand that you've spent considerable time with this problem  but you may want to take a step back and try for a more elegant solution.

Comment: Indeed. [If you have to ask, you're probably doing something wrong.](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2007/03/01/1775759.aspx) (Not quite the same thing, but close enough)

Comment: @Sosukodo I have an alternative of using Stacked Widget & then be able to control what is painted, but in that case I have to add buttons which change the index of the widget that is displayed by stacked widget & I dont get a continuos scroll as I would have got without the stacked widget.

Comment: Why are you calling repaint after the loop? That's probably not necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I understand you don't want to discard your code. I'd try one of these, starting from the easiest:

- Are you using a [`QScrollArea`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qscrollarea.html) or are you simulating it using scroll bars? The `QScrollArea` probably already discards paint events to children widgets that are off the viewport. Assemble the grid off-screen. Otherwise, Qt will recalculate and repaint the layout every time you add a new widget. ([Here is a complete example](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/fe8c343763db96ded195).)

  ```
  QWidget* widget = new QWidget(); // This is an invisible widget.

  for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
      for (int j = 0; j < 100; j++) {
          QLineEdit* lineEdit = new QLineEdit();
          lineEdit->setText(QString("I am the line edit at (%1, %2)").arg(i).arg(j));
          layout->addWidget(lineEdit, i, j);
          if (j % 10 == 0) {
              // Do not block the UI thread while the UI is being assembled.
              qApp->processEvents();
          }
      }
  }

  // The layout will be calculated only once, here:

  scrollArea->setWidget(widget);
  widget->show();
  ```
- If that doesn't work, create an [event filter](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#installEventFilter) that has a reference the visible rectangle. Event filtering is a useful technique in which you can intercept events targeted at one or more widgets and decide if they should be discarded before being handled.

  In your case, when you intercept a `QPaintEvent`, check if the target widget intersects the visible rectangle. If it does, pass the event along to the target widget. If it doesn't, discard the event.

  I don't know the specifics of how you scroll your UI, so I leave the calculating the visible rectangle up to you. The event filter code would be something like this.

  ```
   bool MyClass::eventFilter(QObject *obj, QEvent *event)
   {
      if (event->type() == QEvent::Paint) {
          if (QWidget* widget = qobject_cast<QWidget*>(object)) {
              QRect visibleRectangle = somehowGetVisibleRectangle();
              if (visibleRectangle.intersects(widget->geometry())) {
                  return false;
              } else {
                  // Returning true means "drop this event."
                  return true; 
              }
          }
      }

      // Assuming MyClass extends QWidget. Adjust as necessary.
      return QWidget::eventFilter(obj, event);
   }
  ```
- As a last resort, relayout your UI using [`QGraphicsScene`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsscene.html), [`QGraphicsWidget`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicswidget.html), [`QGraphicsGridLayout`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsgridlayout.html), and [`QGraphicsView`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qgraphicsview.html). The scene graph might be better at discarding unnecessary UI repaints.

Comment: Thank You for your detailed answer! On first read I whole heartedly feel that you deserve those precious 50 pts ;)
Regarding 1st point : Yes I have created a QScrollArea in designer which automatically gave ScrollAreaWidget as the child of QScrollArea. I have made the QScrollArea as my central widget.
Now when I launch the application & push a button which adds specified no of widgets in a QFrame inside the ScrollAreaWidget I am getting a tremendous CPU activity & I have to wait about 2 mins for the window to be enabled. Even after that suppose a function shows a MessageBox then it doesnt work

Comment: Regarding 3rd point : I have absolutely no idea what these Widgets are!

Comment: So, it seems that your problem is assembling the UI, not living with it after it's done. I wrote a quick program that adds 10.000 line edits to a window. See if it helps: https://gist.github.com/anonymous/fe8c343763db96ded195

Comment: I dont know why you got that impression.
My current code adds the QLineEdit & QLabel objects perfectly in the QGridLayout & it is displayed correctly as well!
Its just that it takes too much time. If I create a dummy QGridLayout (which is not displayed) & add all those widgets in it then there is not much time taken for creating & adding 1000's of these widgets to the QGridLayout.
So my conclusion was that painting was take a toll on the CPU.
So as a solution I wanted to reduce the stress on the CPU by stopping the processing of painting activity for widgets that were not displayed.

Comment: In your code I did not understand why you have called processEvents?
AFAIK processEvents processes all pending events in the event loop.
Then why not call repaint instead, since only paint events will be added to the event loop?

Comment: It's both painting and relayouting the grid every time you add a new widget. The dummy approach is actually half way there. Prepare the gridview off-screen and when it is done, add it to the scroll area. (Which, by the way, is what I did in the gist.) The `processEvents` call is to ensure the rest of the UI remains responsible while the program is busy assembling the grid.

Comment: Now I understand the beauty of your code!
I had not noticed that part about QScrollArea. In my project I have added the Scroll Area & the QGridLayout in Designer. I was not removing the GridLayout from the Scroll Area at all!
Maybe that was the problem.
Now I will remove the Grid Layout from Designer & every time I will add the Widgets to the Grid Layout I will:
1. Remove the old QGridLayout from the QScrollArea
2. Create a new QGridLayout
3. Add all the Widgets into the Grid Layout.
4. scrollArea->SetLayout(myGridLayout);

Comment: BTW the eventFilter solution did NOT work!
I set the filter on all the Widgets in my Grid Layout & just for checking purpose I blocked the Paint Event for all of them.
Then despite doing this after running it took approximately the same time only that it did not show the widgets.
As said earlier I will now try the Scroll Area solution & get back to you.
Thanks for all the help mate, I don't have words to express my gratitude towards you...

Comment: Yeah, I supose Qt is smart enough to not route paint events to widgets that are clipped off-screen. If that's the case, the event filter is just pointless overhead. I should have checked the source code.

Comment: Hey andref I implemented your solution & it works like a charm. Thank You so much the time has drastically reduced (2-5 secs for 3000 widgets).
But there is a small problem.
Suppose after everything is added to my window then say I open task manager. My window is also open but is behind task manager.
Now if I move the task manager & click anywhere in my window then I think everything is repainted again, because the main window becomes white & there is heavy processing for 2-5 secs & then everything displayed again.

Answer (score 1):

First of all. Are you sure you are solving your problem in the right way? Perhaps you will be happier with QTableWidget? Its cells can be editable and then QTableWidget will take care of creating and maintaining QLineEdit for the cell that is being edited.

Comment: I am not sure that is the right way!
Just imagine the excess memory that will be taken by the QLineEdit objects apart from the QTableWidget & its items.
Plus I have already developed majority of the software for QLineEdit.
Now changing it for accomodating QTableWidget will be a huge pain for me.
I am using the current combination of QLineEdit & QLabel which makes my UI look clean although the user will be able to see less data compared to that in QTableWidget, I am happy with that.

Comment: @CAD_coding You misunderstood me. You do **not** need to create QLineEdit and QLabel to use QTableWidget. You create QTableWidget and populate it with data. Set the cells you want to keep as labels "non-editable". Leave the rest default (editable). That's it. QTableWidget will itself take care of providing editor for the cell that was being selected for editing (either by user clicking or you calling editItem). There will be no need for 500 QLineEdit.

Comment: ok maybe I did not read your answer carefully, sorry about that!
But I have already styled my QLineEdit & QLabel. Plus some of the properties that a QLineEdit gives me are not found for QTableWidget like Validator.
So can you please tell me how to do what I have asked in the Question?

Comment: You can custom-style and validate cells using a `QTableVIEW` with a custom `QTableModel`, however.